# Warnings with Homebrew

Tags: warnings, homebrew

I did everything from this link http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/#lion-install

But when I do command "brew doctor" I see warnings:

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew
>   directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to
>   determine if software packages are installed, and what additional
>   flags to use when compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed
>   via Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew
>   provided script of the same name. We found the following "config"
>   scripts:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin/gpg-error-config
> /usr/local/bin/ksba-config
> /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
> ```
>
> Warning: Your Homebrew is not installed to /usr/local You can install
>   Homebrew anywhere you want, but some brews may only build correctly if
>   you install in /usr/local. Sorry!

I don't know what to do with that. I want to install the calabash-cucumber gem, but when i try to do that, it says that can't find files.